# Laravel 5 Service API queries with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to create Service API for search data using database.

This is my current query:

```
  public function show($fructose,$lactose,$polyols,$fructan )
    {
        $FodMaps = FodMap::where('fructose','=',$fructose)->
        where('lactose','=',$lactose)->
        where('polyols','=',$polyols)->
        where('fructan','=',$fructan)->
        get();
        return $FodMaps;
    }
```

My service URL is:

```
/api/service/lactose=high/fructose=high/polyols=high/fructan=high
```

It should contain high and low as values. But sometime it comes with value "none" like:

```
/api/service/lactose=high/fructose=high/polyols=none/fructan=none
```

What I want is if it contain any "none" values, escape that item from query and do the search. Because current query search all 4 values.

Ex: if URL is comes with values like this:

```
/api/service/lactose=high/fructose=high/polyols=high/fructan=high
```

It will check the results which matches all 4 items.

But if it comes with this:

```
/api/service/lactose=high/fructose=high/polyols=none/fructan=none
```

It will search columns only lactose, fructose and polyls, and give the results, no need to check the value of fructan column.

Answer (score 0):

Use function to check varables

```
$FodMaps = FodMap::where(function($query) use($fructose,$lactose,$polyols,$fructan){
   if($fructose != 'none'){
     $query->where('fructose','=',$fructose);
   }
   if($lactose != 'none'){
     $query->where('lactose','=',$lactose);
   }
   if($polyols != 'none'){
     $query->where('polyols','=',$polyols);
   }
   if($fructan != 'none'){
     $query->where('fructan','=',$fructan);
   }
})
->get();
```